# What is the "distributional derivative" of a Brownian motion?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $\emptyset\ne I\subseteq\mathbb R$ be an open interval and $A:C_0^\infty(I)\to\mathbb R$ be a distribution. Then, $$\langle{\rm D}A,\varphi\rangle:=-\langle A,\varphi'\rangle\;\;\;\text{for }\varphi\in C_0^\infty(I)$$ is called *distributional derivative* of $A$.

> Let $B=(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a Brownian motion. How is the distributional derivative of $B$ with respect to $t$ defined?

Comment: I've found this term in the following paper: http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0377042708003178/1-s2.0-S0377042708003178-main.pdf?_tid=a704a996-acb7-11e5-b001-00000aacb360&acdnat=1451234228_e36ed3e5f5b1e386f60a272321cc6bab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably *distribution derivative of $B$* refers to  $\varphi\mapsto\int_0^\infty \varphi(s)\,dB_s=-\int_0^\infty \varphi'(s)B_s\,ds$, on the domain comprising smooth functions supported in  compact subsets of $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this the definition of so-called "white noise"? Also, is it known whether or not the distributional derivative of B is a continuous distribution-valued process?

Comment: no it's a distributional real-valued process

Answer (score 1):

The distributional derivative by your definition of a Brownian motion $B$ is just the "white noise process".

Indeed, the Brownian motion is nowhere differentiable almost surely, so we have to make use of the distributional derivative ([generalized functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))).