# Confusion about the covariance of the Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

When studying the Wiener process, I learned that the variance of this process is $Var(W_t) = t$, (which can be proven by calculating the quadratic variation) and furthermore that $\mathbb{E}W_tW_s = \min (t,s)$. However, looking into the Physics literature, one often comes across Langevin equations such as

$$dX(t) = u dt + v \xi(t) dt,$$

where $\xi(t)$ is said to be a Gaussian white noise with $\langle \xi(t)\rangle = 0 $ and $\langle \xi(t)\xi(t') \rangle = \delta( t-t')$. See for example [[1]](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-39320-0). Now what I expect is that $\xi(t)$ is actually shorthand for $\frac{dW_t}{dt}$ which of course is not well-defined but one could consider the ratio of increments $\Delta W_t /\Delta t$. However, even if this explanation were true, I still don't really know where the covariance $\langle\xi(t)\xi(t')\rangle = \delta (t-t')$ comes from. So my question is, what precisely is $\xi(t)$ and where does this expression for the covariance come from?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134193/what-is-meant-by-a-continuous-time-white-noise-process

Comment: A way of formalizing the idea of "white noise" in continuous time is to use the theoretical apparatus developed by Hida. I advice you to give a look to the book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-017-3680-0

Comment: thanks @Chaos I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in  [What is meant by a continuous-time white noise process?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134193/what-is-meant-by-a-continuous-time-white-noise-process), [Importance of white noise and Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312653/importance-of-white-noise-and-brownian-motion) and [What is "white noise" and how is it related to the Brownian motion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639320/what-is-white-noise-and-how-is-it-related-to-the-brownian-motion), we can have define the White-noise process $X$ as a distribution over differentiable functions in terms of Brownian motion

\begin{equation}
(X, f) = -(B, f') = -\int_0^\infty B(t) f'(t) dt.
\end{equation}
Or alternatively using the Itô integral as a distribution over $L^{2}$-functions
\begin{equation}
(X, f) = \int_0^\infty f(t) dB_t,
\end{equation}
(this is the most common function space to define white-noise over).

From here we indeed observe that by taking $f_{i}(t)=\frac{1}{\epsilon}1_{B_{\epsilon}(x_{i})}(t)$ we have by Itô-isometry
\begin{align}
E[(X(x_{1})(X(x_{2})]\approx& E[(X, f_{1})(X, f_{2})] = E\int_0^\infty f_{1}(t)f_{2}(s) dB_t dB_s\\
=&\int_0^\infty f_{1}(t)f_{2}(t)dt=c\frac{1}{\epsilon}1_{|x_{2}-x_{1}|<\epsilon}\approx \delta(|x_{2}-x_{1}|).
\end{align}